# NSSplitView resize only one subview

Tags: cocoa

I have an NSSplitView with a single vertical divider as the contentView of a window, but when I resize the window, the splitview the vertical divider moves around-- for example, if I shrink the window horizontally the divider "drifts" to the left instead of maintaining its absolute pixel offset.

How do I set the NSSplitView so that when I resize horizontally, it only resizes the rightmost  subview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the holding priority.